# Naming convention for RESTful state specific endpoint

Tags: rest, restful-url

I have the following situation.

Headless CMS with CRUD endpoints using `/posts/` which restrict access to an authenticated Users *posts*. i.e. GET to `/posts` returns all of the currently authenticated Users Posts.

I would like an endpoint which only returns posts which are *'publish'* i.e. their `publish_at` date is less than the current time.

I was using `/posts/published` though I believe this to not be good practice.

***Essentially, I wish a public endpoint to only provide resource of a specific state. Or is this goal in itself inherently the issue?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is perfectly fine. All of these are valid ways to handle this:

```
GET /posts/published
GET /posts/bystate/published
GET /posts?state=published
GET /published-posts
```

Comment: I'd assume the question is asking for best practices, not just "anything goes"?

Comment: @MartinWickman I wouldn't say anything goes, but the above are all common enough patterns that they are good enough choices. Internal consistency is ultimately the most important. I like #2 the least, but used #1 #3 and #4 in different systems

Comment: Thanks @Evert I went with #1 it was my preferred to begin with.

I do agree though convention over configuration.